# Password protect a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, password-protection

**WHAT:**

Is there any way to create a password protected file, to prevent unauthorised writing, in python3? The main focus is on writing, not necessarily on reading.

This file should be appendable, by the python program, given the correct password.

The solution should not be OS specific.

**WHY:**

My server needs to log message details and write them to a file, in order to mitigate repudiation attacks. The file obviously has to be write protected or else this purpose is defeated.

**HOW:**

Any ideas?

**Note:**

I've looked at putting the files in a protected zip folder with pyminizip and locking file permissions with os.chmod commands. However, I've found none of these solutions to work for me.

Comment: The method you described should work fine. What is the problem with those (error message?)?

Comment: Who exactly are you protecting your log file from? If it's a user on your system, then if they can write to the file at all, they can almost certainly also delete or truncate it, defeating the logging. If it's a remote attacker, they can't modify your files at all, with or without a password.

Comment: @Blckknght makes sense. I'm now using this: `with os.fdopen(os.open('test.log', flags, 0o022), 'a') as fout: \newline fout.write("logging info")` to restrict permissions. It works for the purposes I need it.

Answer (score -1):

I think You Could Do Something Like This, I Haven't Tested it though :V

> """ Python Password Check """

```
import hashlib
import sys

password = "pasword"

def main():
    # Code goes here
    print "Doing some stuff"
    sys.exit(0)


while True:
    input = raw_input("Enter password: ")
    if hashlib.md5(input).hexdigest() == password:
        print "welcome to the program"
        main()
    else:        print "Wrong Password"
```

Comment: and? how will this prevent a file from being written by any process?

Comment: I see the concept you're going for here, but it's not really what I was looking for. I wanted a solution guided more towards preventing an unauthorised user from just opening the created file in a text editor and changing its contents. I found a solution though, thank you - see my comment on the original question.